# Can I use my Android phone (Galaxy S7) to emulate an RFID card?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

So my understanding is that because my Android phone is High Frequency (13.5khz) and my apartment rfid tag is Low Frequency (125khz), that the phone cannot read the apartment rfid tag.

Is it possible to get a 125Khz rfid tag reader for my computer (probably usb) to get the information of the tag, and then have my android device emulate that same information?

I would like to find a way to use my Android phone as my rfid key for my apartment building.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your phone will ever be able to emulate 125kHz cards, it is a totally different physical layer from the 13.5 MHz NFC standard.

In the unlikely case you had access to the building's access control system (I once tried a similar trick in the coworking space where I waste my days: the look the facility manager gave me was enough for me to abandon the idea), you could convince them to accept 13.5 MHz cards: many modern readers are able to read both kinds of cards, and the readers are the expensive part of the installation. Then you would need to output the same ID as read in your 125kHz card with the phone, and somehow program the access control system to recognize it.
A fun project, but you would really need to have a lot of tinkering access to all parts of the system. Great for a university lab, for example.